# How can I deal with Android update paroject path error?

Tags: android

What to do with this error:

`C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\tess-two-master\tess-twoa>android update project --path`

'android' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the path to android exe in your sys environment variables. on windows, i think it's under your system's control panel somewhere. and if you have not downloaded the android sdk yet, first do that and then set the path accordingly.

Instructions: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html

Comment: thanx alott for the answer that was a little mistake in my enviroment variable so it wasnt working...

Comment: @khyatipandya please accept and/or upvote my answer if it helped correct your mistake.